# Sudden Certificate Verify Failed on Xero Public Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xero-api, xeroizer

Our staging server is connecting to our Xero Public Application perfectly fine, that is up until now (Dec 7, 2016). For some strange reason it is now returning the following error:

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

Here is the code snippet that we are using to connect to Xero.

`@xero_client = Xeroizer::PublicApplication.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
   :logger => Logger.new('log/xero.log', 'weekly')
request_token = @xero_client.request_token(:oauth_callback 
    => "#{APP_DOMAIN}/oauth/callback")`

Then the app fails at this line, and throws the `SSLError` specified above.

Anyone knows the root cause of this?

Details:

- We are using `Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)`
- We are using `Ruby on Rails 4.1.7`, `Ruby 2.1.8p440`
- We are using `Xeroizer 2.16.4` gem
- SSL on the server seems OK, as per checking with 3rd-party sites that check if SSL is properly installed in the site;
- Changing the APP_KEY and APP_SECRET to a Partner Application and changing the constructor to `Xeroizer::PartnerApplication`, and adding relevant extra parameters works (meaning server SSL installation is *not* the issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were running in to this problem as well - updating to version `2.16.5` of the Xeroizer gem resolved the issue for us.

Comment: This is the correct answer as mentioned by the maintainer of Xeroizer near the bottom of [this Github issue](https://github.com/waynerobinson/xeroizer/issues/285#issuecomment-265017377)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have to set `ca_file` as nil.

`@xero_client.client.consumer_options[:ca_file] = nil`

It might have to do with the fact that the built-in `ca-certificates.crt` that came with the gem is outdated.

In our server, the xeroizer crt file is found at `/home/deploy/.bundler/mergethat/ruby/2.1.0/gems/xeroizer-2.16.4/lib/xeroizer/ca-certificates.crt`. It will have a different path depending on your ruby gem/bundler/rvm setup.

Comment: If this is your solution, please mark this answer as correct with the tick <---

Comment: @Sinkingpoint I'm meaning to do that, but I can only accept my solution tomorrow (need 2 days to do that) :)